# How can objects of a nested classes access the object that they're nested in?

Tags: java

How do I get the parent this object from a method in the inner class?

```
class OuterClass {
    public outerMethod() {
         // this refers to the object in the outer class
    }
    class InnerClass {
        public innerMethod() {
             // this refers to the object in the inner class
             // How do I get my current parent object
        }
    }
}
```

One way is to add a method like

```
public OuterClass getthis() {
    return this;
}
```

Any other suggestions? Is there a way from java itself ?

Comment: Updated the class names. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: With parent being anonymous, mission becomes even more impossible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
outerClass.this.method()
```

Class name should start with a capital, it reduces confusion in cases like this one.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
class outerClass {
    public outerMethod() {
         // this refers to the object in the outer class
    }
    class innerClass {
        public innerMethod() {
             // Here's how to get and use the parent class reference
             outerClass daddy = outerClass.this;
             daddy.outerMethod();

             // However, you can also just call the method, and 
             // the "outer this" will be used.
             outerMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

BTW - it is egregiously bad style to declare a class with a name that doesn't start with a capital letter.  Expect to be reminded of this, *repeatedly*, if you choose to ignore the conventions.

Answer (score 0):

`outerClass.this` does the trick. Your class names should start with a capital letter for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
outerClass.this.outerMethod();
```

This obviously does not work on static inner classes, as there is no enclosing instance of the outer class.

And before I forget, read the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). CLass should start with uppercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

```
public outerClass getthis() {
    return outerClass.this;
}
```